# NotFound Failure in Spring Integration Test of Health Indicator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I want to write a simple test for a custom HealthIndicator, which is defined in its own module separated from the module of the Spring application.
The HealthIndicator is pretty simple:

```
@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().withDetail("my-health", "okay").build();
    }  
}
```

This is the test:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class, MyHealthIndicator.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyHealthIndicatorTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void healthTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/management/health")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

And this is the simple Test Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class, MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"debug:true", "management.endpoints.enabled-by-default:true", 
    "management.endpoints.web.base-path:/management", "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health"})
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

The test of the health endpoint returns a 404 - Not Found.

In the logs I see that the TestDispatcherServlet has no mapping for the health endpoint:

```
12:48:38.309 [main] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /management/health
```

but why?

In the logs I see also that the HealthEndpoint actually is created:

```
12:48:38.013 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'healthEndpoint'
```

But the mapping in the TestDispatcherServlet seems not to be configured. How can I enable the mapping?

Please note: I want to test my Health Indicator without a SpringBootApplication. Isn't that possible at all?

Edit:
Nothing special in the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in defining the test property source.

Instead of

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path:/management
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default:true
```

it should be

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/management
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
```

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html#properties-- ":" as well as "=" is supported

Comment: @Gregor Ohh unable to replicate the scenario in local. Can you please share the POM file?